# Bootstrap navbar notification badge

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website which allows users to send messages to each other. I get number of new messages using AJAX. Therefore, I just need to find a way how to display a **badge** in users's navbar.

Here is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I want the **badge** to be created using `<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">1</span>`.

My code for **navbar**:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-laravel" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Website</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="messages">Messages <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">People <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Photos <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a></li>
                <li><a class="nav-link" href="#">Register</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: What you are describing is dynamic behavior. You'll need some javascript to listen for messages and dynamically create the element on the dom for you. Or if you're doing server side programming you can implement it on the backend and pass it upstream with the api on page load.

Comment: I know, it is not a problem. I already have an AJAX call every 5 seconds to check for new messages, so I know when user receives a new message and how many new messages he has. I just need to add a badge to his navbar to notify him.

Comment: Oh! In that case, have you tried in the success handler of your ajax a loop that would iterate over the collection and do something like `$("#Messages").append('<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">totalCount</span>')`? It seems like you would just run a quick count on all of those then append it inside of the `li` on your nav.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

according to the image you posted, you can add the badge in the `messages` parent `<li>` like :

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:right;margin-bottom:-10px;">1</span> <!-- your badge -->
    <a class="nav-link" href="messages">Messages <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
</li>
```

( assuming no javascript needed since you said you already have the `ajax` function ready to update the badge value ).

ofcourse, you can extract the inline styling to an external stylesheet

(here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k6x40tct/2/ )

hope this helps.

Comment: I had to use `margin-bottom: -12px` to have all nav items vertically aligned.