# Change the size of a bootstrap pill badge?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I can get a [pill badge](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/#pill-badges) using this method (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49242906/5783745) & jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/k6x40tct/2/)):

```html
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="float:right;margin-bottom:-10px;">&nbsp;</span>
```

[image]

How can I decrease the size of the dot? (note, I tried wrapping the `<span>` in `<p>` but that messed up formatting and didn't change the size of the dot)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/badge/#pill-badges):

> Badges scale to match the size of the immediate parent element by using relative font sizing and em units.

So if u change the font size of the parent element or the font size of the span itself,  your badge size will change too

Here is an exaple

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<h1>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">&nbsp;</span>
</h1>

<h2>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">&nbsp;</span>
</h2>

<h3>
  <span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">&nbsp;</span>
</h3>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="font-size: 5px;">
  &nbsp;
</span>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="font-size: 10px;">
  &nbsp;
</span>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="font-size: 15px;">
  &nbsp;
</span>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary" style="font-size: 20px;">
  &nbsp;
</span>
```

Comment: Changing the font size seems to work, but only to a certain point, after a certain size (still quite large), I keep decreasing the font-size but it doesn't change size. Any ideas?

Comment: I edit my snippet and as you can see the 1st horizontal dot becomes very small. So i have to assume that something else messes with your badge. May be the content of the badge or an attribute of the parent element.

Comment: The dot definitely responds to the `font-size` in your snippet. There must be something peculiar with my code that is overriding it or investigate somehow. I will investigate. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

From the question what I feel is you need something like this. No need of any custom classes, if you need more customization use the second example

[image]

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


Inbox<sup><span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary">10</span></sup>
```

It should be possible by overriding the class. You can also do this by editing the bootstrap sass files. Check this if it works for you.

```css
.badge.badge-pill.badge-primary.pill-small {
  padding:2px;
  font-size:.5rem;
}

.badge.badge-pill.badge-primary.pill-medium {
  padding:7px;
  font-size:.75rem;
}

.badge.badge-pill.badge-primary.pill-large {
  padding:7px;
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary pill-small">2</span>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary pill-medium">100</span>

<span class="badge badge-pill badge-primary pill-large">19</span>
```

Comment: I keep decreasing the font-size but after a certain size (still quite large) it won't go any smaller. Any ideas why?

Comment: @stevec maybe some other rules are overriding your rule, try adding more specificity to your class.